# Image not displaying in Python TkInter. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, image, class, user-interface, tkinter

**My code:**

```
...

recomlist = []
class recomclass:
        def recomfunc(self,a,b,c,d):
                self.recomphoto = PhotoImage(file=a)
                self.recomphotolabel = Button(bottompanel, image=self.recomphoto, width=463, height=293)
                recomphotolabel.grid(column=b)
                global recomlist
                recomlist += [a]


                self.recomname = Label(bottompanel, text=c, bg="red4", fg="white", font=("Arial", 30))
                self.recomname.place(x=d, y=255)


sobarecom = recomclass()
risottorecom = recomclass()
lasagnerecom = recomclass()


sobarecom.recomfunc("Soba Noodles.ppm", 0, "Soba Noodles", 0)
risottorecom.recomfunc("Mushroom Risotto.ppm", 1, "Mushroom Risotto", 463)
lasagnerecom.recomfunc("Pizza.ppm", 2, "Lasagne", 926)

...
```

Instead of diplaying the three images, it only displays the first one, and a white background for the other two. What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix this?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python TkInter: Image not displaying. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938590/python-tkinter-image-not-displaying-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Comment: If you believe your previous question did not deserve to be closed, you should explain why you think so in a comment to that question and ask for it to be reopened. Asking the same question again is not the right thing to do here.

Comment: You should get error message when running your code in a console.  Your code may works after fixing the error by changing `recomphotolabel.grid(column=b)` to `self.recomphotolabel.grid(row=0, column=b)`.

Comment: @fhdrsdg Oh, I'm sorry. I'm still getting the hang of using this site. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks.

Comment: @PriyaParashar That's okay, as long as you are willing to learn you should be fine! Another advice would be to try and make a [mcve]. The code as you have posted it requires some work for anyone else to run, since things like `bottompanel` aren't declared and all basic tkinter code and your imports are missing. People are more inclined to help when they can copy-paste your code, see the problem and try to debug it.